# Is there a QuickLook plugin for viewing PlantUML diagrams on a Mac?

Tags: macos, finder, quicklook

I've been working with PlantUML diagrams on my Mac, and I'd love to be able to preview them quickly using the QuickLook feature. I've searched around but haven't found a specific QuickLook plugin for PlantUML.

Does anyone know if such a plugin exists? If not, are there any recommended workarounds to preview PlantUML diagrams using QuickLook?

I've already experimented with various extensions like Glance and Syntax Highlight. When the file has a .puml extension, QuickLook doesn't even allow me to preview the code. However, if I change the file extension to something else, I lose the syntax highlighting in VSCode. I was expecting to be able to preview the PlantUML diagrams or at least the code in QuickLook without having to change the file extension and compromise the syntax highlighting in my editor.

Comment: Syntax Highlight allows you to add file name extensions to its list.